# Xcode 11 Beta 5: Preview on Device not working on iPadOS 13.0 (17A5556d)

Tags: xcode11, ipados

I am trying to "Preview on Device" using Xcode 11 Beta 5 oniPadOS 13 beta 6 (17A5556d), and got this error:

"Cannot preview this file, unexpected error occurred".

Before updating to iPadOS 13 beta 6 (17A5556d), it was working fine.

Anyone know if this is a bug?

thanks

Comment: What does it say in "Diagnostics"?
If the certificate is not trusted you can try:
- Open the Settings app
- Open General
- Open Profiles & Device Management
Choose the affected profile and trust it